# Oracle sql execute sql from varchar field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a table were a sql-where clause is stored:

```
  Table_A
  ID  |  entry
  --------------
  1   |  "(select some_id FROM table_one)"   -- This is stored a VARCHAR(4000)
  2   |  "(select some_id FROM table_one WHERE column_one like 'test')"
```

Is it possible to use this where statement in the entry column as a where in a select?

Something like:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM table_B, table_A 
   WHERE table_B.id = table_A.id
     AND table_B.value IN --and here should be the entry column from table_A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't dynamicly add SQL within SQL.

*Alternatively* you can use encapsulate the query logic in a function and use [Dynamic SQL in PL/SQL.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)

For this you would need to create a function (my_function in the SQL below) that returns a collection of string and accepts a SQL statement as a parameter and write your query this way

```
 SELECT *
   FROM table_B, table_A 
   WHERE table_B.id = table_A.id
     AND table_B.value IN (select column_value from Table(MY_FUNCTION(Table_A.SQL_Statement))
```

**Performance** is not to be ignored with this approach.  I suggest you to evaluate the consequence of context switching before going with this solution

Additionally, you'll have to analyze if **SQL Injection** is a possibility and make sure that no malicious SQL is passed as a parameter to the function

**Sample Code**

```
CREATE TYPE varchar_tab_t AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
/


CREATE OR REPLACE function MY_FUNCTION (sqlstring in varchar2) return varchar_tab_t IS
 v_values_tab varchar_tab_t;
BEGIN

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstring bulk collect into v_values_tab;
  return v_values_tab;  
END MY_FUNCTION;
/


with table_a (id, SQL_STATEMENT) as 
  (select 1, 'Select 1 from dual union select 2 from dual union select 3 from dual' from dual)
, table_b (id, value) as 
  (            select 1, 1 from dual 
    union  all select 1, 2 from dual 
    union  all select 1, 5 from dual -- this one should not be shown
   )  
 SELECT *
   FROM table_B, table_A 
   WHERE table_B.id = table_A.id
     AND table_B.value IN (select column_value from Table(MY_FUNCTION(Table_A.SQL_Statement)))
```

**Result**

```
1   1   1   Select 1 from dual union select 2 from dual union select 3 from dual
1   2   1   Select 1 from dual union select 2 from dual union select 3 from dual
```

Comment: Okay I'll try out the function!